# Printing list to table

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing

I have a piece of code

```
resultDict = {}
for startCity in places:
    for endCity in places:
        startLocation = startCity[0] + ' ' + startCity[1]
        endLocation = endCity[0] + ' ' + endCity[1]
        resultLocations = [startLocation, endLocation]
        resultId = ','.join(resultLocations.sort())

        if startLocation == endLocation or resultId in resultDict:
            continue

        dlat = math.radians(float(startCity[2])-float(endCity[2]))
        dlon = math.radians(float(startCity[3])-float(endCity[3]))
        a = math.sin(dlat/2) * math.sin(dlat/2) + math.cos(math.radians(float(endCity[2]))) \
            * math.cos(math.radians(float(startCity[2]))) * math.sin(dlon/2) * math.sin(dlon/2)
        c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1-a))
        d = radius * c
        resultDict[resultId] = d * 0.621371

print resultDict
```

that produces the following onscreen when using the `print` statement:

```
(0.0, (['Millersville CA'], ['Millersville CA']), 0.0)
(1626.614065545485, (['Millersville CA'], ['Millersville IL']), 1616.3457942569537)
(1789.8845362720158, (['Millersville CA'], ['Millersville IN']), 1778.7968284940225)
(2295.8829666956335, (['Millersville CA'], ['Millersville MD']), 2281.198586905769)
(1595.039113682296, (['Millersville CA'], ['Millersville MO']), 1584.3029694701652)
(2082.089905489436, (['Millersville CA'], ['Millersville NC']), 2068.1505623183266)
(1937.855421683643, (['Millersville CA'], ['Millersville OH']), 1927.2582650063941)
(2304.425345768765, (['Millersville CA'], ['Millersville PA']), 2290.4979215838316)
(1771.801667686284, (['Millersville CA'], ['Millersville TN']), 1759.8880673544743)
(2106.8263361464506, (['Millersville CA'], ['Millersville WV']), 2093.504423623986)
(1838.7000061834806, (['Millersville CA'], ['Millersville MI']), 1832.9430747114486)
(1626.614065545485, (['Millersville IL'], ['Millersville CA']), 1616.3457942569537)
(0.0, (['Millersville IL'], ['Millersville IL']), 0.0)
(165.46706149552824, (['Millersville IL'], ['Millersville IN']), 164.45127349792836)
(669.3166714199295, (['Millersville IL'], ['Millersville MD']), 664.8533524270723)
(143.7059918008934, (['Millersville IL'], ['Millersville MO']), 144.75572344683556)
```

What it is doing is calculating the distance between a bunch of cities and then producing the result as a list with the distance in miles, then the two cities names, and then the Pythagorean Theorem distance between the two cities as kind of a check.  How would I go about formatting a print statement to print the results out as something like this:

[image]

I want this to print out on the screen, so how would I go about using `print` and formating it correctly to have the column headers as the cities and then input the correct number for miles?

What I came up with was this code which doesn't do quite what I want...it only spits out the first pair of cities and then moves on to the next pair and prints them below the first pair:

```
    print "\n\n             {0:^}".format(resultDict2),"\n\n{0:^}".format(resultDict3),"  {0:^12.5}".format(resultDict4),"\nGC           {0:^22.5}".format(resultDict1)
```

Here's a few examples of the printed statement:

```
             Millersville MI 

Millersville TN      553.22    
GC                   549.55        


             Millersville MI 

Millersville WV      434.49    
GC                   433.64        


             Millersville MI 

Millersville MI       0.0      
GC                    0.0
```

Is there a way to get the code to print the next pair of cities to the right of the last pair instead of down below?

I appreciate the help...I've been stuck on this for the past couple days and can't seem to get it to work.

---

EDIT:

Was asked about `places`...here is what went into it:

```
245939,Millersville,CA,Kern,35.30385,-118.45786,767,2516,Loraine,6,29,-2005993.585,-7850.609146
422981,Millersville,IL,Christian,39.45115,-89.15814,200,656,Owaneco,17,21,582900.2782,239679.282
439235,Millersville,IN,Marion,39.8531,-86.09165,228,748,Indianapolis East,18,97,838665.4307,307491.2101
590805,Millersville,MD,Anne Arundel,39.05955,-76.64802,47,154,Odenton,24,3,1647634.706,343137.5611
722401,Millersville,MO,Cape Girardeau,37.43283,-89.79954,140,459,Millersville,29,31,543086.0153,10195.50234
1021470,Millersville,NC,Alexander,35.85569,-81.18342,293,961,Millersville,37,3,1320855.874,-81032.00324
1048977,Millersville,OH,Sandusky,41.312,-83.28131,212,696,Helena,39,143,1053471.336,497736.4912
1181260,Millersville,PA,Lancaster,39.99788,-76.35413,99,325,Conestoga,42,71,1650717.971,451187.4979
1293977,Millersville,TN,Sumner,36.37116,-86.71,154,505,Goodlettsville,47,165,824583.7325,-86143.9105
1555125,Millersville,WV,Marion,39.4612,-80.14813,330,1083,Fairmont West,54,49,1345239.636,332269.94
1617722,Millersville,MI,Wexford,44.27667,-85.55978,425,1394,Boon,26,165,829275.484,803975.6286
```

Comment: The data structure your working with makes no sense. You have a tuple of lists but all of the lists in that tuple (the cities) have only a single element!

Comment: @msvalkon:  How do I go about fixing that problem?

Comment: `','.join(resultLocations.sort())` should error as `list.sort()` doesn't return anything

Comment: I'd be interested in what `places` looks like exactly

Comment: Maybe use a dictionary where each city is a key and the value is a list of tuples `(city, distance)`. Like this  http://bpaste.net/show/aw2tVf43afQ7ixuMGzaE/ If you look at that closely, it's a structure for a weighted graph.

Comment: @cmd...I'll add the places.csv as an edit above...

Comment: @msvalkon:  there are varying numbers of cities depending on the csv file I pull in to run the code on...how would I account for that in your suggestion?

Comment: By adding the keys and values whenever you encounter them. Lists and dictionaries are mutable data structures. Make the distances a [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to make your life a little easier (`distances = defaultdict(list)`) and then adding a new key is simply: `distances[new_origin].append((destination, miles))`

Comment: @msvalkon...okay...I'm a little lost...where would that all go in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would fix your data structure (its kinda messed up)

```
resultDict = {}
cities = [' '.join(c[:2]) for c in places]
for startCity in places:
    for endCity in places:
        start = ' '.join(startCity[:2])
        end = ' '.join(endCity[:2])
        resultDict[start, end] = calc_distance(startCity, endCity)
```

Where `calc_distance` returns your two distances in a list (normal and GC). like

```
def calc_distance(startCity, endCity):
    # whatever magic you need to do to calculate your distances
    return [distance, gc_distance]
```

Now resultDict should look like

```
{
    ('Millersville CA', 'Millersville CA'): [0.0, 0.0],
    ('Millersville CA', 'Millersville IL'): [1616.3457942569537, 1626.614065545485],
    ('Millersville CA', 'Millersville IN'): [1778.7968284940225,1789.8845362720158],
    ('Millersville CA', 'Millersville MD'): [2281.198586905769,2295.8829666956335],
    ('Millersville CA', 'Millersville MO'): [1584.3029694701652, 1595.039113682296],
    ('Millersville CA', 'Millersville NC'): [2068.1505623183266, 2082.089905489436],
    ....
}
```

then printing out is easier

```
print "\n"
f = "{:>22}" * (len(cities) + 1)
print f.format("", *cities)
for c in cities:
    print
    print f.format(c, *[resultDict.get((c, e))[0] for e in cities])
    print f.format("[GC]", *[resultDict.get((c, e))[1] for e in cities])
```

Comment: I get an error:  join() takes exactly one argument (2 given) for the line cities = [' '.join(c[0], c[1]) for c in places]

Comment: can you post the entire code you used to get the resultDict you posted there...I'm simply getting errors using Python 2.7

Comment: @Tony sorry about that, fixed the joins

Comment: @Tony hard to do, since I don't have exactly what your places looks like.  My places had each place [0] as the name, [1] as the state.  If that is not how your places look you could substitute a slice that would return those.  I took out the calculation since its not important for the structure but as long as it comes back as a list like I show it should be good.

Comment: I added a couple lines to create a list  calc_distance = lenght_mi, distance...but now the code gives me an error 'tuple' object is not callable for the line resultDict[start, end] = calc_distance(startCity, endCity)...any idea why this is happening???

Comment: The `calc_distance` I reference should be a function that returns a list of calculated values for 2 cities.